Montreal Forced Aligner(MFA) taking too much time(almost 18 days still going on) to train a 33 GB corpus
WE are  using Montreal Forced Aligner (MFA) 3.x to train an acoustic model on a large dataset (~33GB of audio and transcripts in an Indian language). The training process takes an extremely long time(almost 18 days still going on) to complete.
Here are the details of my setup:

Hardware: [16 vCPU, 16 GB RAM]

Audio Format: WAV files

Corpus Details: 33GB.

Command Used: mfa train with default parameters.

Version: MFA 3.x


Can we reduce the training time? Can we predict a ballpark time for the total time taken for training?

Are you training a model on a 33GB corpus using CPU?? That's going to take very, very long. You need to be using GPUs

@ParmanM.Alizadeh We have started using GPU but there was no consumption while training the model. So we have started using CPU.

It doesnt automatically use GPU when available. you have to specify that yourself

The official MFA documentation explicitly outlines its reliance on the Kaldi speech recognition toolkit. Kaldi primarily uses CPU-based computation for training and alignment tasks.
